# convert PDF into TIFF with 600dpi and jpg 96 dpi

Tags: python, linux, imagemagick

I want to convert pdf into tiff with 600 dpi and jpg with 96 dpi from Python script using ImageMagick.

i was done this task using (imagemagick) command line but i want to convert pdf into tiff and jpg using Imagemagick in python ,

can you please help me for that......

Answer (score 3):

**First you have to load a wrapper around imagemagick library**

using [PythonMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/):

```
from PythonMagick import Image
```

or using [pgmagick](https://pypi.org/project/pgmagick/):

```
from pgmagick import Image
```

**then, independently from the library you loaded, the following code will convert and resize the image**

```
img = Image()
img.density('600')  # you have to set this here if the initial dpi are > 72

img.read('test.pdf') # the pdf is rendered at 600 dpi
img.write('test.tif')

img.density('96')  # this has to be lower than the first dpi value (it was 600)
# img.resize('100x100')  # size in px, just in case you need it
img.write('test.jpg')  


# ... same code as with pythonmagick
```

Comment: but i just want convert pdf to tiff and jpg using imagemagick,, not using python interface for imagemagick (pythonmagick)...

Comment: so I think Rakesh answer is what you're looking for :)

Comment: I tried to add PyhtonMagick library but it is not available. Anybody was able to get it?

Comment: @Amadeus: PythonMagick is an old library so I've added a more recent alternative, PgMagick, that is better documented and should be easier to install. Hope it helps.

Comment: @furins I found another solution but I will mark your answer for future use. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)** to execute the imagemagick command

```
import subprocess
params = ['convert', "Options", 'pdf_file', 'thumb.jpg']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```