# Convert tiff to PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf, tiff, converters

I'm looking for a package or some library that can help me

1. Input a number of `tiff` files from a folder.
2. Convert each `tiff` file to `PDF`.
3. Write `PDF` files to another folder.

The package `tiff` does not convert the file unfortunately. Is anybody aware that a package like this exists?

Comment: Don't think there is anyone that has done that. I don't think it would be a great use case. Is there any reason you can't use an external program to do the conversions, e.g. [python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868387/convert-pdf-into-tiff-with-600dpi-and-jpg-96-dpi)

Comment: I'm just comfortable using R. The conversion process is part of a process that is getting automated. We use a software that does the conversion, but want to eliminate its use. The ETL is done by using R, so I was hoping that I could use the same script to do the conversion.

Comment: I think I have an idea. If I install ImageMagick, then I can use R to run command lines that I would have run on a windows command prompt termminal. ImageMagick commands can be run through command prompt. What do you think? @Shawn Mehan

Comment: that would work, certainly. Alternatively, you could just run a single python script rather than all of the individual calls. That would be a more modular approach. good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a go and now I have a code that does the conversion. I just wrote it all in R. Thanks again @ShawnMehan

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to convert a tiff file to pdf with the following code :

```
library(magick)
library(tiff)
Rlogo <- system.file("img", "Rlogo.tiff", package = "tiff")
im <- image_read(Rlogo)

pdf("tiff_to_pdf.pdf")
plot(im)
dev.off()
```